# EditText sem Foco pela Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Existe algum comando na `Activity` que impeça um `EditText` de receber foco, mesmo com o usuário clicando? Ou isso só pode ser feito pelo XML?

Eu tenho um repositório que está conectado a um banco de dados e preciso que esse repositório esteja preenchido antes que o usuário preencha os campos. Portanto até que o usuário sincronize pela primeira vez, ele não poderá preencher os campos.

Por isso preciso de uma forma para travar o `EditText` até esse repositório ser preenchido.

Comment: Modo read-only talvez? Só que ai o campo não poderá ser editado.

Comment: @diegofm

Modifiquei minha pergunta, talvez agora fique mais claro o que estou procurando.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Olá, vê se algum dos métodos abaixo te ajuda.

```
edittext.setFocusableInTouchMode(boolean)
edittext.setFocusable(boolean)
```

Depois que terminar o carregamento você habilita novamente (pode usar o `setEnabled(boolean)` também).

Comment: Era isso mesmo o que eu procurava

Comment: Certo então, bons trabalhos.

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer isso no próprio código fazendo o seguinte:

```
EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt);
edt.setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: Isto não vai só remover o foco, mas vai bloquear o componente também.

Comment: É isso, me equivoquei, tem que usar o seguinte:
edt.setFocusable(false);

Comment: Edite a resposta então, ainda está com o método errado.

Comment: Obrigado por me lembrar! Já está editado!